# Storing files in MySql database using jsp and servlet.

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to store files (text or image) in mySql database using jsp and servlet.

This is index.jsp.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Upload to Database Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1>File Upload to Database Demo</h1>
    <form method="post" action="FileUploadDBServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstName" size="50"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName" size="50"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Portrait Photo: </td>
                <td><input type="file" name="photo" size="50"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

2. This is my FileUploadDBServlet.

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.SQLException;

   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
   import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
   import javax.servlet.http.Part;


   @WebServlet(name = "FileUploadDBServlet", urlPatterns ={"/FileUploadDBServlet"})          
   public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {

      // database connection settings
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rep";
         String dbUser = "root";
         String dbPass = "";

       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
       HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       // gets values of text fields
       String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
      String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");

      InputStream inputStream=null; // input stream of the upload file

   // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
   Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
   if (filePart != null) {
       // prints out some information for debugging
       System.out.println(filePart.getName());
       System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
       System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

     // obtains input stream of the upload file
        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();

   }
    //System.out.println(inputStream);
   Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
   String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client

   try {
       // connects to the database
       DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

       // constructs SQL statement
       String sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, ?)";
       PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

       statement.setString(1, firstName);
       statement.setString(2, lastName);

      if (inputStream != null) {
           // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
           statement.setBlob(3, inputStream);
      }

       // sends the statement to the database server
       int row = statement.executeUpdate();
       if (row > 0) {
           message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
       }
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
       ex.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       if (conn != null) {
           // closes the database connection
           try {
               conn.close();
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       // sets the message in request scope
       request.setAttribute("Message", message);

       // forwards to the message page
       getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
   }
   }
   }
   ```
3. And this is my Message.jsp

   ```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>Message</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
         <h3><%=request.getAttribute("Message")%></h3>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
   ```

The message page displays "ERROR: No value specified for parameter 3".
So, I think null value is being stored in inputStream. Why is it so and how can it be handled?
Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to save the file in a location and save the location in the database.

Comment: @actuallyashish, I think inputstream is null.Debug and inspect the value of the inputstream.

Comment: @Masud Can you provide some links or tutorials where I can study about the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `statement.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.BLOB);` if yoúr inputstream is null.

```
if (inputStream != null) {
    // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
    statement.setBlob(3, inputStream);
} else {
    statement.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.BLOB);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Using setNull() helped, and now I get the message "File uploaded and saved into database". However, basic problem remains that I am not able to store my data in the database. Null is being stored in all the columns. Now, I understand it for the photo column (since, setNull) but what about first_name and last_name? Also, how can I store values in the column photo?

Comment: @actuallyashish Can you print out `request.getParameter("firstName");` to see if the parameter is set in the request?

Comment: I tried that before and as a matter of fact, both are null. I can't understand why those parameters aren't being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

As you are submitting form data with **enctype="multipart/form-data"** For this you have to mention @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = "max file size") in your upload servlet.